# Multiple WAPs: Bandwidth, Frequency Considerations

Tags: wireless-networking, router

The router in my LAN closet does 2 and 5 GHz.

In the kitchen, I have a single-band 2 GHz WAP, and in the garden shed I have another single-band 2 GHz WAP.

All are set to Bandwidth = 40 MHz, Wireless Network Mode = N-Only.

The kitchen WAP and the LAN closet router both come up with multiple bars on my smart phone from almost anywhere in the house.   The garden shed WAP will register one bar... but only sometimes.

I have read the "*Wi-fi Router Neighbor-Friendly Mode?*" thread and it *sounds* like I'm asking for trouble with 3 WAPs all set to 40 MHz.... OTOH, the focus of that thread was multiple WAPs each on a different network.

The Questions:

- Are these things in danger of butting heads?
- Should I re-set them to Bandwidth = 20 MHz?  Bandwidth = Auto?
- Are there any tools that I could use on an Android smart phone, 
  iPod, or WiFi-enabled laptop to make my own analysis?

Comment: What channels are they on?